# Can't open file by fstream cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I can't open file with fstream despite the file is in project. Here's the code:

```
std::fstream fst("Resources/test.txt");
std::string fileStr;
std::getline(fst, fileStr);
log("line\n %s", fileStr.c_str());
```

File test.txt is in Resources folder in my project, checked. I'll appreciate any help from u guys. Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you assuming the *current working directory* is the parent of the `Resources` folder?

Comment: Talking about current working directory, do you mean directory where is my  class which works with stream? Sorry if I didn't understood you right.

Comment: Which OS you are running the code at?

Answer (score 1):

I think fstream is not able to use in cocos2d-x. neither fopen.

You can use cocos2d::FileUtils API.

```
cocos2d::FileUtils * file_utils = cocos2d::FileUtils::sharedFileUtils();
std::string full_path = file_utils->fullPathForFilename("test.txt");
long int data_size;
unsigned char * file_data = file_utils->getFileData(full_path.c_str(), "r", &data_size);
cocos2d::log("file_data is %s", file_data);
```

*note: not "Resources/test.txt" but "test.txt"

Comment: oops. You should write "delete[ ] file_data;" finaly.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I need to write some information to this file. How can I do that without fstream class?

Comment: @EugeneAlexeev A couple of things.  Firstly if this answer has helped you then why haven't you upvoted it?  Don't you think it's beneficial to encourage help from others?  Secondly, this answer doesn't use `fstream` so what does your comment mean?

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm always trying to vote up to all people who're trying to help me but I don't have enough reputation, so I can't give my thanks, and it makes me upset really. As for my second question, I meant how can I write some string to file using this way which you proposed to me? Of course, your help is very helpful, and if I could vote up to u, I definitely would do it. P.S.: Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

i think @yuni_net_liberty is wrong.

fstream and fopen is able to use in cocos2d-x. i can understand why some c++ code is not able to run in a c++ project.

the reason why fstream not work is because there are two kinds of resource. in bundle and out of bundle. resources in bundle can not be read use ftream and fopen. they can only read in native code(objctiveC, java)

Comment: Thanks for your response! What's the difference between in bundle and out of bundle? Is it like if resource is in "Copy Bundle Resources" section so this is "in bundle?

Comment: No, the issue is the directory.  The *current working directory* of the process won't be the same as the app bundle, which is why the code fails in the question.  @yuni_net_liberty's answer is correct as they recommend using `FileUtils::fullPathForFilename()` to get the full-path to the file within the bundle, regardless of the CWD.